# Pandas column positions are shifted with non-alphabetic language

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, utf-8

When non-alphabetic language are used as Pandas index, the whole row is shifted to right.
The code works without problem but when table is printed, it looks not only bad but also confusing.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4), \
                  columns = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], \
                  index = ['new jersey', 'colorado', 'utah', 'arizona'])
```

For the code above, the result follows;

```
            one  two  three  four
new jersey    0    1      2     3
colorado      4    5      6     7
utah          8    9     10    11
arizona      12   13     14    15
```

but when "new jersey" is replaced with "北海道", it looks like this.

```
          one  two  three  four
北海道         0    1      2     3
colorado    4    5      6     7
utah        8    9     10    11
arizona    12   13     14    15
```

Does anybody know why this happens and how to fix it?
I tried Korean, Japanese and Taiwanese but results were all the same no matter how short the string is.

Thank you.

Comment: Pandas is doing everything correct here. It's just a font issue when displaying the text, see https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/23513 for an illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem when displaying a dataframe in a terminal. If you try the same code in a Jupyter notebook, you will not see this misalignment.

Terminals treat CJK characters as wide characters which take up more than one terminal cell. So if you do not adjust for the wide characters text will be miss aligned.

[pandas.set_option](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.set_option.html) has two relevant options `display.unicode.east_asian_width` and `display.unicode.ambiguous_as_wide`. The first of these should be sufficient for your needs:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> import numpy as np
>>> pd.set_option("display.unicode.east_asian_width", True)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4), \
    columns = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'], \
    index = ['北海道', 'colorado', 'utah', 'arizona'])
>>> df
```

Comment: It  works regardless of the string length.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the amount of spaces required is calculated based on the width of a standard ASCII character. I do not think you can modify this behavior.

Try using [display()](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html) for the nice representation.

[image]